# Ajax Call in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am making JQuery Ajax call in asp.net, I am returning String with my WebMethod, But on success of ajax call I am getting complete HTML of page in result.I also used type: "get" but no luck, below is my code for ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyPage.aspx/GetData", //url to point your webmethod          
    success: function (Result) {
        if (Result != "")
            alert( Result);
        },
    error: function () { alert('error'); }
});
```

---

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public string GetData()
{
    //getting value from Database and returning
}
```

I am calling this Ajax in MyPage.aspx

Comment: can you post the webmethod?

Comment: @Xikinho90  I have posted the method as well, GetData()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this. With the contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyPage.aspx/GetData", //url to point your webmethod          
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (Result) {
        if (Result != "")
            alert( Result);
        },
    error: function () { alert('error'); }
});
```

Comment: Unknown web method GetData.<br>Parameter name: methodName